# how to set a timeout to a java httpClient per request

Tags: java, httpclient, settimeout

I use a httpClient of apache in java to call REST APIs which is configured as below in a static block of class, what I want is to change the connection timeout per request. is it possible? how?

```
 static {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager pool = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    pool.setMaxTotal(ChatSettings.HTTP_CLIENT_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
    httpClient = HttpClients
            .custom()
            .setConnectionManager(pool)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(
                    RequestConfig
                            .custom()
                            .setConnectTimeout(DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT)
                            .setSocketTimeout(DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT)
                            .build()
            )
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can implement for sure is to follow this example: https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/5.1.x/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/ClientAbortMethod.java

It demonstrates how a client can fire a request, but eventually change it's mind and tell the server it no longer wants to receive the response.
Combine this with a 'watchdog' thread that fires after some time/when the time runs out.